# Prevent JNLP from being cached in the Java Web Start cache

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

when i launch a JNLP it's always being cached in the Java Web Start cache. Is there a way to prevent it from being cached? Some attribute/property inside it?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, but you might look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: I want to hide that content from the user so that he doesn't try to launch the app with some different parameters (my jnlp is dynamically generated).

Comment: It may help to update your question to reflect this; an alternative may be possible.

Comment: JNLP files that have an HREF that includes query parameters (e.g. the bit after `?` in `href="the.jnlp?file=the.file?format=plain"` typically are 'treated differently' to other JNLP files.  I cannot say for sure whether they are cached, but they would typically not appear in the JCP, or produce splash screens, or shortcuts for the desktop or programs menu.

Comment: I don't think this will improve security in any way. If users want to tamper with software running on their computer then they will. If they don't have the JNLP file then they will download it with wget, curl, or similar.

Comment: They are still cached even if i add those parameters. And the thing is my jnlp is dynamically generated, i open it from another app with a one shot token in the url, so it can be consumed only once. So this means that the JNLP might be 'personalized' as well.

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I'm on the same boat.

Comment: @codenamezero I don't remember, it was a long time ago :( However: i have the feeling the href attribute  is the key of the cached JNLP resource, so not writing an href might prevent it from being cached?